# ionic android emulator not finding config.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator, ionic-framework, ripple

If I try to run my ionic app on an android emulator (e.g. via Chrome/Ripple, or via the Android emulator on my Mac) I get the error:

```html
GET http://localhost:8100/config.xml 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't get this error when testing in Safari.

Do I have to explicitly copy the config.xml file to platforms/android/assets/www?